# How to work with a buffer and binary files

Tags: c++, vector, binary, buffer

I am trying to write a vector per string to a binary file and then read it back. I just can't go any further because I have problems with my buffer. I try to take it as a char * but I can't.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void write_bin() {
    vector<string> vec = {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4"};
    ofstream bin_out("binary.bin", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::trunc);

    if (!bin_out.is_open()) {

        // Set n size of vec first
        bin_out.write((char *) vec.size(), sizeof(int));

        for (string s : vec) {
            size_t size = s.size();
            bin_out.write((char *)size, sizeof(size));
            bin_out.write(&s[0], size);
        }
        bin_out.close();
    }
}

void read_bin() {
    ifstream bin_in("binary.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
    string s;
    char *buffer;
    bin_in.read(buffer, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < atoi(buffer); ++i) {
        bin_in.read(buffer, sizeof(int));
        size_t size = atoi(buffer);
        bin_in.read(&buffer[0], size);
        s = buffer;
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    write_bin();
    read_bin();
}
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Words to live by: If you're C-casting in C++ code to squelch warnings/errors, you are, in all likelihood, already doing something wrong.

Comment: IMHO the approach is wrong. You should use classical de/serialization techniques and overwrite the inserter and extractor operator. There is no need to store the size. Simply write the vector line by line to a text file and then read everything back with ````std::getline````. That is totally easy and also better understandable.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting to make the value of `size` a pointer, when you in fact want a pointer to what's stored in `size`.

So

```
size_t size = s.size();
bin_out.write((char *)size, sizeof(size));
```

should be

```
size_t size = s.size();
bin_out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
```

(apply everywhere where you've made the same error)

Also, this part is messed up:

```
    char *buffer;
    bin_in.read(buffer, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < atoi(buffer); ++i) {
```

`atoi` tries to convert a byte string, like "`10`" into an integer. Unless the first `char` in `buffer` is in the range `('0', '9']` (where '0' is usally a `char` with the value 48), it'll return `0`. You need something along the line:

```
    size_t buffer_size;
    bin_in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer_size), sizeof(buffer_size));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < buffer_size; ++i) {
```

...but read below for how to properly write and read sizes in binary format to/from a file.

---

> What is the right way to do this?

Unless you are planning on storing strings containing `\0` or `\n`, using 4 or 8 bytes (common sizes of a `size_t`) to store the size is just a waste - and it makes your code non-portable since you don't take endianess into consideration.

I suggest writing the strings using `\0` or `\n` to mark the end of them and use `getline` to read them back.

If you want to save a few bytes when storing the size of really big vectors, make sure you store it in a format that can be read on all platforms. You currently store it in a format that is non-portable.

- `size_t` does not have the same `sizeof(size_t)` on all platforms.
- The endianess is not the same on all platforms.

An attempt to store the sizes in a platform agnostic way could be to use a function to convert back and forth between the native format and what you store in the file. You probably have the `htons`/`ntohs` and `htonl`/`ntohl` functions available - or you could write your own.

Naive implementation in C++20:

```
using size_type = std::uint16_t; // use a fixed width type to store sizes

size_type convert_size(std::size_t value) {
    if(value > std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max())
        throw std::length_error("value to big: " + std::to_string(value));

    size_type retval = value;

    // decide on a format that can be read on all platforms.

    static_assert(std::endian::native == std::endian::little ||
                  std::endian::native == std::endian::big,
                  "Mixed endianess not supported");

    // Here I've opted to go for big endian:
    if constexpr (std::endian::native != std::endian::big) {
        // swap the byte order if your platform uses little endianess
        std::reverse(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&retval),
                     reinterpret_cast<char*>(&retval) + sizeof(retval));
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Then a program like:

```
int main() {
    size_t foo = 100;
 
    auto size_to_write_to_file = convert_size(foo);
    std::cout << size_to_write_to_file << '\n';

    size_t size_read_from_file = size_to_write_to_file;

    std::cout << convert_size(size_read_from_file) << '\n';
}
```

Would either print `25600` and `100` or `100` and `100` depending on the platform you're running it on - but it would always end up with `100` as the size when you read it back.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your question, you were asking:

> What is the right way to do this?

The answer is: Use serialization.

Do not try to store complex data as binary data. This will very often not work, because of different properties of the operating system and/or filesystems. The most portable approach is to use text files or other formatted structures like XML or JSON or whatever. You may also use libriaries like Googles protobuf

But for this simple example we will do the serialization by ourselves. We create a data structure and simply overwrite the extractor and inserter operators. With that, we can use all IOStream facilities for our own type. It then doesn't matter, if we insert our data into `std::cout` or `std::ofstream` or wherever. So, this is the preferred approach.

Please see the follwoing very simple example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct MyData {
    // Our vectro with strings
    std::vector<std::string> text{};

    // Override extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, MyData& md) {
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line); md.text.emplace_back(std::move(line)));
        return is;
    }
    // overwrite inserter operator
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MyData& md) {
        std::copy(md.text.begin(), md.text.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};

const std::string fileName{"test.txt"};

int main() {

    // Our test data
    MyData myData1{ {"text1", "text2", "text3"} };;

    // Open file for writing and check, if it could be opened.
    if (std::ofstream ofs{ fileName }; ofs) {

        // Write all data from test vector to file
        ofs << myData1;
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError. Could not open file '" << fileName << "' for writing\n\n";

    // Open file for reading and check, if it could be opened.
    if (std::ifstream ifs{ fileName }; ifs) {

        // We will read from the file to this new variable
        MyData myData2{};

        // Read all data from file
        ifs >> myData2;

        // Show result on screen
        std::cout << myData2;
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError. Could not open file '" << fileName << "' for reading\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

You need to compile with C++17 enabled, because I use `if` statements with initializers.

Comment: Looks nice, but doesn't it avoid the main topic "_How to work with [...] binary files_"?

Comment: Yes, it does avoid the topic. My message is: Do not use binary files except for PODs. So, not for ````std::vector```` and other classes.